# Using label in multicols

Tags: two-column, labels, multicol

To produce 4 figures (2 on top followed by 2 at the bottom) in a **two-column article**, I am currently using:

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\floatsetup[table]{capposition=top} %caption on top of table

\begin{figure*} 
\begin{multicols}{2}
    \label{fig:image1}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{image1.pdf}\par 
    \label{fig:image2}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{image2.pdf}\par 
\end{multicols}
\begin{multicols}{2}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{image3.pdf}\label{fig:image3}\par 
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{image4.pdf}\label{fig:image4}\par 
\end{multicols}
\caption{To be added}
\label{fig:z_evolution_zcosmo}
\end{figure*}
```

I get what I required, except that the **`label{}`** I have added for each of the sub-figure does not work!

**How can I add labels to each of my sub-figures in `multicols` so that I can use them for referencing??**

Comment: The first two labels do not refer anything because there is nothing that can be referred. The is no caption etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since there is no `\caption` or a manual `\refstepcounter{figure}` the first labels `fig:image1` and `fig:image2` will either refer to nothing or accidentally use the last counter type that was refstepped before (In this example: none)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure*} 
\begin{multicols}{2}
  \caption{My first image}
    \label{fig:image1}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{image1.pdf}\par
    \caption{My second image}
    \label{fig:image2}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{image2.pdf}\par
\end{multicols}
\begin{multicols}{2}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{image3.pdf}\label{fig:image3}\par 
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{image4.pdf}\label{fig:image4}\par 
\end{multicols}
\caption{To be added}
\label{fig:z_evolution_zcosmo}
\end{figure*}



In figure \ref{fig:z_evolution_zcosmo} and \ref{fig:image1} and \ref{fig:image2}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Other possibilities: `subfig` package and `subcaption` packages etc.

Comment: When I use the above, I get the error: `! Package floatrow Error: Caption(s) lost.` at the second caption

Comment: @ThePredator: Well, I am not using floatrow. Your fragment does not reveal anything about `floatrow`. Of course floats are lost in `multicol` environment

Comment: well I also need `floatrow` for placing captions on top of the table. Is there any way to overcome this?

Comment: @ThePredator: Please post a full example with `floatrow`, perhaps it can be done then

Comment: I have edited the question with some of the packages I am using..

Comment: @ThePredator: I fear you're are out of luck. `multicol` and floats just don't work (as far as I know)

Comment: Can you please if possible post an answer or guide me to a page wherein I can see examples using `subfig` or `subcaption` packages for a two-column article?

Comment: I am actually writing a paper for MNRAS. Got to know from your profile that you too are a Doctor In Astrophysics!!

Comment: @ThePredator: Yes, but I quit that almost 10 years ago.